# C# Access Database Update Syntax Error

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Is there something wrong with this query?

```
"UPDATE tb_EmployeeMasterList SET [EmployeeID] = " + txt_EmpId.Text +", [LastName] = '" + txt_LN.Text + "', [FirstName] = '" + txt_FN.Text + "', [MiddleName] = '" + txt_MN.Text + "', [PositionOrSkill] = '" + txt_PorS.Text + "', [BasicSalary] = " + txt_Basic.Text + ", [Allowance] = " + txt_Allow.Text + ", [Total] = " + total + ", [EPAproposedBonus] = " + txt_Bonus.Text + ", [Remarks] = '" + txt_Remarks.Text + "' WHERE ([LastName] = '" + LN + "' AND [FirstName] = '" + FN + "');"
```

I keep on Getting syntax error on that query alone.

Comment: and what's that error you get???

Comment: Syntax Error in Update statement

Comment: print your query and see what it generates. Post it in question

Comment: What do you mean print it?

Comment: `Console.WriteLIne(sqlstring)`

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with this, but it could fail depending on the data being passed in. For example if one of the fields contained an apostrophe you'd have some trouble, or if the numeric fields don't validate out non-numeric data. Obviously, we have to take your word for it that the table and field names match also!

Comment: @SteveLovell yes, they do. I've checked like 5 times already.

Comment: Have you managed to get sqlstring as per Rahul's comment? If so, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a pair of single quotes missing:

```
"UPDATE tb_EmployeeMasterList SET [EmployeeID] = " + txt_EmpId.Text +",
```

Should be:

```
"UPDATE tb_EmployeeMasterList SET [EmployeeID] = '" + txt_EmpId.Text +"',
```

Comment: Still the same error. The EmployeeID is an integer/number in my database that's why I dont have single quotes on it.

Comment: That makes sense. So as Rauhl suggested: could you post the generated sql string that you get at runtime here?

Comment: i forgot to update this question sorry. what i did was to change the data type of EmployeeID in my database to String. I just got tired and wanted an easy way out. haha!

Answer (score 0):

Try to fire the WHERE statement without brackets

```
"UPDATE tb_EmployeeMasterList SET [EmployeeID] = " + txt_EmpId.Text +", [LastName] = '" + txt_LN.Text + "', [FirstName] = '" + txt_FN.Text + "', [MiddleName] = '" + txt_MN.Text + "', [PositionOrSkill] = '" + txt_PorS.Text + "', [BasicSalary] = " + txt_Basic.Text + ", [Allowance] = " + txt_Allow.Text + ", [Total] = " + total + ", [EPAproposedBonus] = " + txt_Bonus.Text + ", [Remarks] = '" + txt_Remarks.Text + "' WHERE [LastName] = '" + LN + "' AND [FirstName] = '" + FN + "';"
```

Answer (score 0):

If `total`, `LN` and `FN` values come from variables not Textboxes then the syntax is OK but Textbox then add .Text after them otherwise it gives the Syntax error.

Comment: they are variables in the class. Sorry, forgot to say that. it has Integer and String values respectively in them.

Comment: As I tested there is no problem. If still, debug and then share the generated sql syntax.